# Virtualbox Headless: not starting via systemd

Tags: virtualbox, archlinux, systemd

Already tried [this Topic](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=147591) but doesn't solved it

I have placed a file called vbox.service under /lib/systemd/system/vbox.service with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Virtualbox Headless VM

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/VBoxHeadless --startvm 4decf7c1-7eda-461c-92aa-835d2405a22e
ExecStop=/usr/bin/VBoxManage controlvm 4decf7c1-7eda-461c-92aa-835d2405a22e poweroff
User=my_user

[Install]
WantedBy=muti-user.target
```

If I start and stop it via
`sudo systemctl start vbox` and `sudo systemctl stop vbox`, everything works fine
Then i entered the following:
`sudo systemctl enable vbox`, but it wont start at boot
Here is the output

```
sudo systemctl status vbox
vbox.service - Virtualbox Headless VM
      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vbox.service; enabled)
      Active: inactive (dead)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/vbox.service

Jan 05 02:38:59 exia pulseaudio[1428]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
Jan 05 02:40:08 exia systemd[1]: Started Virtualbox Headless VM.
Jan 05 02:42:02 exia systemd[1]: Stopping Virtualbox Headless VM...
Jan 05 02:42:02 exia VBoxManage[1546]: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Jan 05 02:42:02 exia VBoxHeadless[1375]: Oracle VM VirtualBox Headless Interface 4.2.6_OSE
Jan 05 02:42:02 exia VBoxHeadless[1375]: (C) 2008-2012 Oracle Corporation
Jan 05 02:42:02 exia VBoxHeadless[1375]: All rights reserved.
Jan 05 02:42:02 exia VBoxHeadless[1375]: VRDE server is listening on port 3389.
Jan 05 02:42:02 exia VBoxHeadless[1375]: VRDE server is inactive.
Jan 05 02:42:02 exia systemd[1]: Stopped Virtualbox Headless VM.
```

/usr/bin/VBoxHeadless --startvm 4decf7c1-7eda-461c-92aa-835d2405a22e works fine
Any ideas, though?

Answer (score 4):

[This page on the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Starting_virtual_machines_with_a_service) contains a slightly more flexible systemd.service file and some additional options which may hold the key.

That page also mentions that VirtualBox 4.2 has a built in auto start mechanism which may work better.

`/etc/systemd/system/vboxvmservice@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=VBox Virtual Machine %i Service
Requires=systemd-modules-load.service
After=systemd-modules-load.service

[Service]
User=user
Group=vboxusers
ExecStart=/usr/bin/VBoxHeadless -s %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/VBoxManage controlvm %i savestate

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: It is not working for me. after **systemctl enable vboxvmservice@xp**, it says **ln -s '/etc/systemd/system/vboxvmservice@.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxvmservice@xp.service'**, and nothing happens when executing **systemctl start vboxvmservice@xp**. By the way, since systemctl can only be executed by root, does it mean that this  method always requires root privilege to run a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

Your service is not being enabled for auto-start at bootstrap because you've given it the name of a non-existent target to be part of when it is enabled. The correct spelling is `WantedBy=multi-user.target`.

Answer (score 0):

If after running `sudo systemctl enable vbox` the symlink `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vbox.service` is not created, you can go ahead and create it manually with

```
sudo ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/vbox.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vbox.service
```

That should fix the problem.

[Some similar problems solved that way](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=146154).

Another alternative that worked for me, was to save the `.service` file on `/etc/systemd/system/` instead of `/lib/systemd/system/`. Doing this allowed `systemctl enable` to work properly.